# How to write an updateable application on mac

Tags: macos, auto-update

I have simple application for Mac, how can I implement autoupdate feature? May be there is default solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) is a free framework that makes it really easy to integrate update functionality into your application.

Comment: sparkle is really suit my needs

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to implement it is to distribute your application on the Mac AppStore. They handle all application distribution and application updates very, very nicely.

Other than that, you need to write your own:

1. Check version on start
2. If there is a new version, offer to download it
3. After download offer a INSTALL & RELAUNCH button: this button, will close the application, update it, and launch it again.

Comment: 1. Mac AppStore is a good choice, but it require additional user efforts